# Non Admin Openstack user unable to create compute instances on Horizon

Tags: openstack

**Problem Statement:**
Non Admin user is unable to create instances using Openstack Horizon Dashboard.

**Errors:**
Errors seen in sequence on the top right of the page are:

- Error: Forbidden. Insufficient permissions of the requested operation
- Error: Unable to retrieve the flavors.
- Error: Unable to retrieve the images.
- Error: Unable to retrieve instances. Details
  Policy doesn't allow os_compute_api:servers:detail to be performed. (HTTP 403) (Request-ID: req-7c777849-af66-48dc-9b1e-48fdeaafbc5d)

**Other Symptoms:**

- When choosing the "Compute > Instances > Launch Instance" wizard - the use can not see the option to choose image / flavors.
- Admin user CAN choose these options and launch an instance.

**Versions:**

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Openstack Antelope release
- 4 nodes cluster: 2 Compute, 1 Controller, 1 Storage
- This is a new, manually deployed openstack cluster

**Troubleshooting done:**

- Uncommented policy lines in nova_policy.yaml in /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/conf
- Restarted services, rebooted the controller node.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Non-Admins are not expected to create instances. They can partially manage instances assigned to them, but that's about it. Otherwise non-admins could easily over-provision a server and degrade performance for everyone. If the goal is to have anyone allowed to do anything, then you may want to just grant everyone admin access. Mind you, this would just create a different set of problems.